# Prestashop Webservices API: HTML in description gives an error 404

Tags: xml, rest, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using the [Prestashop Webservices Library](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) to create and update products.
I have no problems when creating them but on update, even if I do the same with no issue on create products, it gives me an error 404 when adding HTML to the description field.

I'm able to update the product if I remove the html, but it should work with it too.
I [extended SimpleXMLElement to add a CDATA](https://github.com/fawno/SimpleXMLExtended) in the Prestashop Library, but the result is the same

```
require_once('class/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');


try {
     
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://mywebsite', 'MYKEY', false);

        $idProduct = 30;
 
        $xmlResponse = $webService->get(['resource' => 'products', 'id' => $idProduct]);
 
        $updateProductXML = $xmlResponse->product[0]; 
        unset($updateProductXML->manufacturer_name); //Not writable, remove them
        unset($updateProductXML->position_in_category);
        unset($updateProductXML->quantity);

        $updateProductXML->name->language[0][0] = "TEST";
        $updateProductXML->description->language[0][0] = "This is not working if I add this: &amp; ";
 
        $response = $webService->edit([
            'resource' => 'products',
            'id' => (int) $updateProductXML->id,
            'putXml' => $xmlResponse->asXML(),
        ]);
 
    } catch ( PrestaShopWebserviceException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

if I remove the `&amp;` in the description field it works and update the product, else it returns a 404 error even if the description is in a CData node):

Not working as well:

`$updateProductXML->description->language[0][0]->addCData('test &amp: test');`
`$updateProductXML->description->language[0][0]->addCData('juste normal text but in cdata');`

Any idea?

thanks :)

> Prestashop version: 1.7.7.3, fresh install

Comment: Check by passing debug mode true in PrestaShop Webservices Library to check actual error

Comment: @ArunVishwakarama it's already on, but it doesn't return an error, it makes a 404 error (a normal one not a webservices one, so it returns the 404 error page).
the problem is only when adding special chars in the description, the same code without it works, and if I put incorrect datas in others fields, the webservices returns an error 400 as it should

Comment: To debug I tried this:

It works when doing an urlencode of the description field, then doing a specific urldecode around line 1594 of the WebserviceRequest.php

Comment: Then there must be issue with CDATA please check by printing data that it’s file

Comment: @ArunVishwakarama I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

as asked, here is the sent XML, it's correctly formed even with the CData:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <product>
        <id>30</id>
        <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
        <id_supplier>0</id_supplier>
        <id_category_default xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/categories/31">31</id_category_default>
        <new></new>
        <cache_default_attribute>0</cache_default_attribute>
        <id_default_image notFilterable="true" />
        <id_default_combination notFilterable="true">0</id_default_combination>
        <id_tax_rules_group xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/tax_rule_groups/53">53</id_tax_rules_group>
        <type notFilterable="true">simple</type>
        <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
        <reference>mySKU</reference>
        <supplier_reference />
        <location />
        <width>0.000000</width>
        <height>0.000000</height>
        <depth>0.000000</depth>
        <weight>0.000000</weight>
        <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
        <ean13 />
        <isbn />
        <upc />
        <mpn />
        <cache_is_pack>0</cache_is_pack>
        <cache_has_attachments>0</cache_has_attachments>
        <is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
        <state>1</state>
        <additional_delivery_times>0</additional_delivery_times>
        <delivery_in_stock>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">in stock</language>
        </delivery_in_stock>
        <delivery_out_stock>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">out of stock</language>
        </delivery_out_stock>
        <on_sale>0</on_sale>
        <online_only>0</online_only>
        <ecotax>0.000000</ecotax>
        <minimal_quantity>0</minimal_quantity>
        <low_stock_threshold>0</low_stock_threshold>
        <low_stock_alert>0</low_stock_alert>
        <price>27.900000</price>
        <wholesale_price>0.000000</wholesale_price>
        <unity />
        <unit_price_ratio>0.000000</unit_price_ratio>
        <additional_shipping_cost>0.000000</additional_shipping_cost>
        <customizable>0</customizable>
        <text_fields>0</text_fields>
        <uploadable_files>0</uploadable_files>
        <active>1</active>
        <redirect_type>301-category</redirect_type>
        <id_type_redirected>0</id_type_redirected>
        <available_for_order>0</available_for_order>
        <available_date>0000-00-00</available_date>
        <show_condition>0</show_condition>
        <condition>new</condition>
        <show_price>0</show_price>
        <indexed>1</indexed>
        <visibility>both</visibility>
        <advanced_stock_management>0</advanced_stock_management>
        <date_add>2021-04-23 19:04:53</date_add>
        <date_upd>2021-04-26 08:58:22</date_upd>
        <pack_stock_type>0</pack_stock_type>
        <meta_description>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </meta_description>
        <meta_keywords>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </meta_keywords>
        <meta_title>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </meta_title>
        <link_rewrite>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">testttt</language>
        </link_rewrite>
        <name>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">My test product</language>
        </name>
        <description>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[test  test]]>
            </language>
        </description>
        <description_short>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </description_short>
        <available_now>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </available_now>
        <available_later>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/languages/2">TEST</language>
        </available_later>
        <associations>
            <categories nodeType="category" api="categories">
                <category xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/categories/19">
                    <id>19</id>
                </category>
                <category xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/categories/31">
                    <id>31</id>
                </category>
                <category xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/categories/95">
                    <id>95</id>
                </category>
                <category xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/categories/100">
                    <id>100</id>
                </category>
            </categories>
            <images nodeType="image" api="images" />
            <combinations nodeType="combination" api="combinations" />
            <product_option_values nodeType="product_option_value" api="product_option_values" />
            <product_features nodeType="product_feature" api="product_features">
                <product_feature xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/product_features/6">
                    <id>6</id>
                    <id_feature_value xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/product_feature_values/12">12
                    </id_feature_value>
                </product_feature>
            </product_features>
            <tags nodeType="tag" api="tags" />
            <stock_availables nodeType="stock_available" api="stock_availables">
                <stock_available xlink:href="https://mywebsiteurl/api/stock_availables/104">
                    <id>104</id>
                    <id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute>
                </stock_available>
            </stock_availables>
            <accessories nodeType="product" api="products" />
            <product_bundle nodeType="product" api="products" />
        </associations>
    </product>
</prestashop>
```

Answer (score 0):

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://mywebsite', 'MYKEY', false);

Just make last parameter true to enable debug mode and see actual error

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://mywebsite', 'MYKEY', true);

Also unset id too from the response then post data

It should be fine